# How to access a value in nested JSON with all fields concatenated in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, nested, concatenation

Let's say I have this JSON in this variable `person`:

```
{
    "firstName": "First Name"
    "lastName": "Last Name"
    "address": {
        "city": "New-York",
        "street": "Some Street"
    }
}
```

Now, if I want the value of `street`, all I have to do is `person[address][street]`

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do so, let's say I have all the fields concatenated like:

```
const index = 'address:street'
```

I'm looking for a simple way to achieve the value like `person[index]`

Is there a way to do so? thanks!

Comment: the first question would be... why?

Comment: I prefer not to break the concatenation to achieve the value if i can

Comment: `person.address.street`?

Comment: I don't know the fields in advance, therefore the problem.

Comment: What exactly is the data like? Please include a sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I installed [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) and then:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const person = {
    "firstName": "First Name"
    "lastName": "Last Name"
    "address": {
    "city": "New-York",
    "street": "Some Street"
    }
}

const index = 'address.street'; // changed it to be split by . instead of :

_.get(person, index);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string variable that has all the required fields to access the value in the right order like below (fields separated by a dot):

```
    const index = "address.street";
```

Then you can get the requested value by using the eval function in javascript:

```
    eval("person."+index);
```

This returns the required result: "Some street".

Comment: is there a way without eval?

Comment: @MightGod yeah, `let street = address.street;`

Comment: I don't know the fields in advance, therefore the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after but this would work:

```
const cstring = "value1:value2:value3";
const [one, two, three] = cstring.split(':');

console.log(one) // 'value1'
```

So that uses array destructuring.